# How to create Helper Methods on Laravel not a Facade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1, helper

I've read a lot of questions on how to make helper methods in Laravel 5.1. But I don't want to achieve this via a Facade.

```
HelperClass::methodName();
```

I want to make helper methods just like on these methods [Laravel Helper Methods](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/helpers#available-methods) like:

```
myCustomMethod();
```

I don't want to make it a Facade. Is this possible? How?

Comment: You want to make a custom function like array_add()?

Comment: @RobinDirksen Yes Sir. You got it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to go the 'Laravel way', you can create `helpers.php` file with custom helpers:

```
if (! function_exists('myCustomHelper')) {
    function myCustomHelper()
    {
        return 'Hey, it\'s working!';
    }
}
```

Then put this file in some directory, add this directory to autoload section of an app's `composer.json`:

```
"autoload": {
    ....
    "files": [
        "app/someFolder/helpers.php"
    ]
},
```

Run `composer dumpauto` command and your helpers will work through all the app, like Laravel ones.

If you want more examples, look at original Laravel helpers at `/vendor/laravel/framework/Illuminate/Support/helpers.php`

Answer (score 6):

To start off I created a folder in my app directory called `Helpers`. Then within the Helpers folder I added files for functions I wanted to add. Having a folder with multiple files allows us to avoid one big file that gets too long and unmanageable.

Next I created a `HelperServiceProvider.php` by running the artisan command:

`artisan make:provider HelperServiceProvider`
Within the register method I added this snippet

```
public function register()
{
    foreach (glob(app_path().'/Helpers/*.php') as $filename){
        require_once($filename);
    }
}
```

lastly register the service provider in your `config/app.php` in the providers array

```
'providers' => [
    'App\Providers\HelperServiceProvider',
]
```

After that you need to run `composer dump-autoload` and your changes will be visible in Laravel.

now any file in your `Helpers` directory is loaded, and ready for use.

Hope this works!

Answer (score 0):

This is what is suggested by [JeffreyWay](https://laracasts.com/@JeffreyWay) in this [Laracasts Discussion](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/best-practices-for-custom-helpers-on-laravel-5?page=1#reply-28978).

Within your `app/Http` directory, create a `helpers.php` file and add your functions.

Within `composer.json`, in the autoload block, add `"files": ["app/Http/helpers.php"]`. And run

```
composer dump-autoload.
```