# Laravel url alias, mismatch in url generation

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I have a Laravel 5.2 application where I want to display the same page on 2 different domains / routes. I have it working using the following route structure:

The routes to my primary domain:

```
Route::group(['domain' => 'www.primarydomain.com',
              'prefix' => 'demo-page']), function(){
    Route::get('/my-page', 'MyController@index');
    Route::get('/my-second-page', 'MyController@getPageTwo');
}
```

The routes to my secundary domain (note: no prefix!):

```
Route::group(['domain' => 'www.secundarydomain.com',]), function(){
        Route::get('/my-page', 'MyController@index');
        Route::get('/my-second-page', 'MyController@getPageTwo');
}
```

The idea is that both routes will work, and they do. Both www.secundarydomain.com/my-page and www.primarydomain.com/demo-page/my-page work.

The issue is when I now want to generate a link to my second page. For building my URL's in my views, I'm using the following function to generate a link to my-second-page:

```
url('/my-page')
```

This function always generates a link to www.primarydomain.com/my-page, while I need a link to www.primarydomain.com/demo-page/my-page.

Is there any easy solution to resolve this? Can this be resolved using middleware, or will a custom URL function be needed?

Expected results:

`url('my-page')` on www.primarydomain.com should generate a link to `www.primarydomain.com/demo-page/my-page`

`url('my-page')` on www.secondarydomain.com should generate a link to `www.secondarydomain.com/my-page`

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to do that is to [create your own helper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37339475/how-to-create-helper-methods-on-laravel-not-a-facade/37339565#37339565), like `custom_url()` and use it instead of `url()`.

You can look how original `url()` helper works and create similar one. Look here:

https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php#L806

Answer (score 0):

You can assign aliases to your routes.

```
Route::group(['domain' => 'www.primarydomain.com', 'prefix' => 'demo-page']), function(){
    Route::get('/my-page', [
        'as' => 'my_page_prefixed', 
        'uses' => 'MyController@index'
    ]);
    Route::get('/my-second-page', [
        'as' => 'my_second_page_prefixed'
        'uses' => 'MyController@getPageTwo'
    ]);
}
```

And then you can call your aliased route on your blade templates by using  `{{ route('my_page_prefixed') }}` or any other alias.

Comment: This will not be a solution, as both the primary and secondary domain use the same code. So using different aliases per domain is not possible