# How can I write an accessible class in the whole of project?

Tags: php, laravel

I use Laravel framework and this is my current directory:

[image]

As you see, there is a class named `Log` *(the one I've selected)*. Now I need to make it global. I mean I want to make it accessible in everywhere and be able to I make a object *(instance)* of it in following files:

- All files of `classe` folder
- All controller
- `web.php` file of
- All file of views

Anyway I want to be able to make a instande of it and call its methods everywhere like this:

```
$obj = new Log();
$obj->insert($message);
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [create global Laravel helper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37339475/how-to-create-helper-methods-on-laravel-not-a-facade/37339565#37339565):

```
if (! function_exists('log')) {
    function log($message)
    {
        (new Log)->insert($message);
    }
}
```

Put it in `helpers.php` and add this to `composer.json` to load the helpers file:

```
"autoload": {
    ....
    "files": [
        "app/someFolder/helpers.php"
    ]
},
```

Then you'll be able to use this helper globally:

```
log('User added');
```

In views:

```
{{ log('User added') }}
```

**Update**

@stack, you're using wrong syntax for JSON (screenshot in comments), here's correct one:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    },
    "files": [
        "app/Helpers/helpers.php"
    ]
},
```

Comment: Seems correct, thank you, upvote .. just for my information, can't I do that by making a *Facades*  ?

Comment: @stack Facades are for static methods, if you want an instance, a facade doesn't suit with your case.

Comment: You can, but using global helpers is much more robust and easier to use solution for this case.

Comment: Can you please tell me what's the difference between your solution and the other one in the link you provided ? Both of you have used helper, right? so what's the different?

Comment: Both solutions are exactly the same. I just adapted code in my answer for you situation.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin No no, I know your two solutions are the same, my question was about your solution and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37339475/how-to-create-helper-methods-on-laravel-not-a-facade/37339565#37339615)

Comment: Oh, sorry, I get it now. My solution uses composer to load file. Another solution manually loads bunch of files.

Comment: Do you know what are those two red underlines? has my code syntax error? https://i.stack.imgur.com/OIO99.png

Comment: Yes, you're using wrong syntax for JSON file. I've updated my answer with an example. Hope this helps. )

Comment: Sorry for asking too much, it's the last one *(I promise)*, Why did you use `files` word in the composer? Can it be anything else or it is a constant? Also for doing what job do I need to use `files`?