# How can I define some constants for the whole of project?

Tags: php, laravel, configuration, composer-php, constants

[Here is my directory *(the screen-shot in this link)*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41119923/how-can-i-write-an-accessible-class-in-the-whole-of-project). Also I have one more file named `config.php` which contains some variables, like this:

```
<?php

    // db
    $dbname = 'mydb';
    $db_username = 'root';
    $db_password = '';

    // login
    $l_email = 'some@one.com';
    $l_password = 'mypas'

    // details
    $sleep_on_error = 1; // per sec

    // and etc 
    // .
    // .
    // .

?>
```

As you see, I've some variables that are stored into `config.php` file .. I may need each of those variable in every part of my project. So I need to make `config.php` file accessible in the whole of project. So I can add `config.php` file into composer to make it accessible in the whole of project. like this:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    },
    "files": [
        "app/classes/config.php"
    ]
},
```

All I'm trying to do is implementing a easy-configuration-system for my project. Can please tell me am I doing that correctly? Or should I define a class for doing that? or all I'm doing is wrong and I should do something else?

In short, what's the best structure to make a configuration for the project?

Comment: Configs are usually just key/value pairs, so the format should be simple and easy to maintain.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Do you mean I have to make a file *(not `.php` file, something like a xml file)* and parse it for using?

Comment: Are you aware that PHP actually supports proper constants? Because you're using variables here.

Comment: That's one way. We sometimes use *.ini* as the file extension, sometimes *.txt*. It is a personal preference.

Comment: @JayBlanchard The reason many PHP projects actually use a PHP module for configuration is that in constrast to normal text files, under normal circumstances PHP files will never be sent to the client as text, but will always be parsed by the PHP processor and thus don't generate any output, whereas with normal text files you need to make sure with other means that the configuration is never actually sent to the client's browser. So this is actually an additional security feature and your solution - if done wrong - is actually dangerous.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Laravel way is using [config files](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/configuration#accessing-configuration-values). Create `my.php` and put it in `/config` directory and then access constant values globally:

```
config('my.variable')
```

Here's an example of `my.php`:

```
<?php

return [
    'variable' => 15,
    'some-array' => [1, 2, 5],
];
```

Comment: wow great .. the most of your answers are perfect .. thank you man .. just can you please add a working example *(show us how `my.php` looks like)* to your solution?

Comment: Thanks. ) Added an example.

Comment: Is it possible to do the same but for a function? I mean I want to define a function accessible in all controllers. Is that possible?

Comment: @MartinAJ sure. Read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37339475/how-to-create-helper-methods-on-laravel-not-a-facade/37339565#37339565

Answer (score 2):

You can create a file like @Alexey Mezenim has suggested - say `admin-settings.php` in your `/config` directory and populate it with an array containing the constants/values you need globally

```
//admin-config.php
<?php

    return[
        'db' => [
                   'name' => 'mydb',
                   'username' => 'root',
                   'password' =>''
                ],
         'login' => [
                       'email' =>'some@one.com',
                       'password' => 'mypas'
                    ],
         'sleep_on_error' => 1
    ];
```

Then you can access the values anywhere in your application as

```
config('admin-config.db.name')

config('admin-config.login.email')

config('admin-config/sleep_on_error')  

//and so on
```

Comment: U'r welcome. Thanks for the upvote :). Just expanded on Alexey's answer to align it more closely with your question's context.

Answer (score 2):

This is very simple, just in two steps:

**1)** Create a file say `constants.php` under `config/app` and place value in an form of array like:

```
return [
    'APP_NAMEIS' => 'myappname'
];
```

After above step,
**2)** use that code at anywhere by using `Config` Facade like:

```
Config::get('constants.APP_NAMEIS');
```

Hope this clear that how can use the constant anywhere. See attached reference for [more detail](http://laravel.io/forum/06-05-2014-how-to-use-my-constants-in-larvel?page=1).

Answer (score 0):

you can easily add constant configs from files like

```
<? // conf.php
$config = ['dbname' => 'test'];
return $config;
```

`define('config', include('conf.php'));`

`echo config['dbname'];`

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did in my Laravel 5.2 App

First created a php file with name `constants.php` under `my_app/bootstrap/` and written all the constants needed in the whole app in this file;

Sample View of `constants.php`

```
if (!defined('LOGO_URL')) {
    define('LOGO_URL', SITEURL . '/images/' . 'logo.png');
}

if (!defined('GRAVATAR_SIZE')) {
    define('GRAVATAR_SIZE', 100);
}

if (!defined('SITE_NAME')) {
    define('SITE_NAME', 'My App');
}
```

then `require` it to `my_app/bootstrap/autoload.php` like this

```
require __DIR__ . '/constants.php';
```

Now I can access this variable throughout the application!

Hope this helps!