# Where I put my custom functions to be accessed in view (laravel 5.3)?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

My function is like this :

```
function romanic_number($integer, $upcase = true) 
{ 
    $table = array('M'=>1000, 'CM'=>900, 'D'=>500, 'CD'=>400, 'C'=>100, 'XC'=>90, 'L'=>50, 'XL'=>40, 'X'=>10, 'IX'=>9, 'V'=>5, 'IV'=>4, 'I'=>1); 
    $return = ''; 
    while($integer > 0) 
    { 
        foreach($table as $rom=>$arb) 
        { 
            if($integer >= $arb) 
            { 
                $integer -= $arb; 
                $return .= $rom; 
                break; 
            } 
        } 
    } 

    return $return; 
}
```

I want in view, I can accessing like this :

`{{ romanic_number(2) }}`

The result : II

Where I put my custom functions to be accessed in view?

I try put my custom functions in controller, but it's failed

**UPDATE**

I make folder helpers in folder app. Then I make file helper.php in folder Helpers (mysystem/app/Helpers/helper.php)

I put this :

```
<?php

if (! function_exists('romanic_number')) 
{
    function romanic_number($integer, $upcase = true) 
    { 
        ...

        return $return; 
    } 
}
```

I add "app/Helpers/helper.php" in composer.json like this :

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Illuminate\\Support\\": ""
    },
    "files": [
        "helpers.php",
        "app/Helpers/helper.php"
    ]
},
```

Then I run `composer dump-autoload`

There exist error like this :

```
Call to undefined function romanic_number() (View: C:\xampp\htdocs...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [create custom `helpers.php` file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37339475/how-to-create-helper-methods-on-laravel-not-a-facade/37339565#37339565) and define all helpers there:

```
if (! function_exists('romanic_number')) {
    function romanic_number($value)
    {
        $romanic = ....;
        return $romanic;
    }
}
```

And then add it to `composer.json` so Laravel could autoload it:

```
"autoload": {
    ....
    "files": [
        "app/someFolder/helpers.php"
    ]
},
```

Comment: Check if you're using correct path and run `composer dumpauto` command.

Comment: Just checked, works for me. Please show your `composer.json` and file with functions.

Comment: Thanks. The problem is you've added it to wrong `composer.json`. You should add `files` directive to the `composer.json` which is in project's root.

Comment: How do you mean. I am still confused. I add it in composer.json

Comment: @mosestoh you've added it to another `composer.json`, one of those in `vendor` directory. Add it to one in project's root (where `app`, `vendor` etc. directories).

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 3):

Create a file named `helpers.php` in folder `app/Helpers` (first you have to create `Helpers` folder), put all your functions in that file.

Then tell the composer about this file in `composer.json` as:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    },
    "files": [
        "app/Helpers/helper.php",
    ]
},
```

Then do `composer dump-autoload` and you can use it in your view or anywhere else.

For example in view:

```
{{ romanic_number(2) }}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own custom helpers. Create `CustomHelper.php` file and add your function there & include in `composer.json` file as below

```
"autoload": {
        ...
        "psr-4": {
             "App\\": "app/"
        },
        "files" : [
            "app/CustomHelper.php"
             ...
        ]
}
```

Comment: @mosestoh Why there is another `helpers.php` in your composer.json? can you remove it and add only `app/Helpers/helper.php` & try