# Is it wrong to write long php codes in laravel blade file?

Tags: php, laravel

The question is straightforward. I don't prefer to write "controller code" in blade file. However, I can't convert title (user input) to formatted title directly because of locale language differences. I want to write switch case code in blade file like that:

```
    switch ($word_char) {
            case 'a':
            case 'A':
                $word_char_new = 'A';
                break;
            case 'b':
            case 'B':
                $word_char_new = 'B';
                break;
            case 'c':
            case 'C':
                $word_char_new = 'C';
                break;
            case 'ç':
...
```

Is this a good practice or should I avoid it?

Comment: Yes, it is wrong.

Answer (score 3):

It's a bad practice, you shouldn't do anything similar in a controller. [The Laravel way is to create global helper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37339475/how-to-create-helper-methods-on-laravel-not-a-facade/37339565#37339565) in case if you'll use it a lot:

```
if (! function_exists('convertChars')) {
    function convertChars()
    {
        $result = ....
        ....
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Add it to a custom `helpers.php` and autoload it by putting this into `composer.json` which is in Laravel root directory:

```
"autoload": {
    ....
    "files": [
        "app/someHelpersDirectory/helpers.php"
    ]
},
```

Also, since you're trying to convert non-latin characters to latin ones, I guess [this method](https://github.com/alexeymezenin/laravel-russian-slugs/blob/master/src/Slugs.php#L110) from my package will help you to create more concise and readable helper.

Comment: Should I make a help function like your toTranslit function?

Comment: @user2356198 well, it's up to you. Look at it, if you'll understand how it works and you'll like the approach, you can do similar one.