# OOP PHP - Call method from extended class without having to put the class for it

Tags: php, laravel, oop

I have a class in a file like:

```
class foo
{
    public function something()
    {
        return "something"
    }
}
```

Then in an other file I have a class like:

```
class bar extends foo
{

}
```

Now I want to call the something method.
I can do this like `foo::something();`, but I want to just do `something()`. just like it is in Laravel.

Ofcourse I can `require` the file where `foo` is in, but I dont want that, because I think thats kind of dirty.

So, how do I do that?
I've looked around on the internet but did not find an answer. Everthing I find is from like 5-7 years ago.

EDIT:

Look, you just return `view();`

Without `self::` or `this->`

And I am wondering how you do that. **IN VANILLA PHP**

```
public function index()
{

    $categories = Category::categories();
    $posts = Post::latest()->get();

    return view('welcome', compact('posts', 'categories'));
}
```

Comment: Just `something()` means you're calling a function, not a class method.

Comment: How do they do it in laravel then? :/ with the methods like view() or redirect()

Comment: Do what in Laravel?

Comment: For `bar` to extend `foo` the `foo` class must be included.  Then just `$this->something();` or `self::something();`

Comment: @u_mulder calling methods. You can call a method in laravel without self:: or $this->. Just like you would call a function. And I want to be able to do that too.

Comment: You would need to provide a working example, since we don't believe it.

Comment: Laravel uses namespaces and `use` statements instead of `require` statements (just to respond to that specific part of your question)

Comment: Laravel helper `view()` (https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/helpers#method-view) is a wrapper for some other methods.

Comment: @AbraCadaver I updated my question

Comment: `view()` is a standalone function. _The view function retrieves a view instance:_ https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/helpers#method-view

Comment: Oh okay, So that means you cant have a method in the extended class and just call it like a normal function?

Comment: Correct. And source https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php

Comment: Okay, thank you. sorry for my slightly stupid question... :/

Comment: @Luuk as I said in my answer you can do this. You can just create some kind of a wrapper and call static method from your class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These functions are called global helpers. You can [create your own Laravel helpers in custom helpers file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37339475/how-to-create-helper-methods-on-laravel-not-a-facade/37339565#37339565). Helper could be wrapper for some class method or a simle function:

```
if (! function_exists('customHelper')) {
    function customHelper()
    {
        return 'Something';
    }
}
```

To make custom helpers file work add it to autoload section of an app's `composer.json` and run `composer dumpauto` command once:

```
"autoload": {
    ....
    "files": [
        "app/someFolder/helpers.php"
    ]
},
```

Comment: Okay, thanks for you answer but, I think you misunderstood me or I was just not clear in my question, but I want to do it in vanilla php.

Comment: @LuukWuijster it's in vanilla PHP. ) These are just global functions.