# Merge create and edit blade files to 1 file?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I have created a create form `create.blade.php` and a edit form `edit.blade.php` - both form fields are identical.

It quite annoying when I add new fields in the `create.blade.php`, I also need to add fields in `edit.blade.php`.

How can I merge into 1 blade file it so it work for both way for creating and editing (view via db).

For example in `create.blade.php` I have this:

```
<label>Name</label>
<input type="text" name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}">
@if ($errors->has('name'))
  <label class="error">{{ $errors->first('name') }}</label>
@endif
```

In `edit.blade.php`

```
<label>Name</label>
<input type="text" name="name" value="{{ old('name', $category->name) }}">
@if ($errors->has('name'))
  <label class="error">{{ $errors->first('name') }}</label>
@endif
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check if model exists:

```
{{ old('name', empty($category) ? '' : $category->name) }}
```

Also, you may want to check if it's create or update form and change form url accordingly:

```
{{ route(empty($category) ? 'article.create' : 'article.update' ) }}
```

Comment: Is there a way to create like a helper method to do `{{ old('name', empty($category) ? '' : $category->name) }}` ? Something like `populate('name', 'category->name')` or similar?

Comment: Sure, why not? Please check this answer about [creating custom Laravel-like helpers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37339565/1227923)

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" name="name" value="{{ $category ? $category->name : old('name') }}">
```

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, adding a explanation helps op to understand why/how it works.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a partial (fancy name for a smaller template) for your form, and pass that partial the data you require.

Using the example of a booking system:

In your create  blade file:

```
@include('bookings._forms', ['booking' => new \App\Booking])
```

and the edit file ($booking being retrieved on the controller):

```
@include('bookings._forms', ['booking' => $booking])
```

And then your form partial can look like this:

```
<label for="name" class="label">Name</label>
        <input type="text"
                     class="input"
                     name="name" id="name"
                     placeholder="Guest name"
                     value="{{ old('name') ?? $booking->name }}">
```

The good thing with this method is that now you can have ONLY your form elements on the partial and only have to update 1 file when you add fields, AND the actual  tag stays on your create and edit template, so no worries about that either.

Hope that's clear and it helps.