# Change the asset helper url in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

The `asset()` or `URL::asset()` will point to `http://my-url/public/` in default.

Is there any way to change the url of `asset()` to `http://my-url/public/assets/`  ?

I have many asset files which I should use in my blade templates and I don't want to write `assets` any time.

I mean use `asset('js/script.js')` instead of `asset('assets/js/scripts.js')` in my blade templates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, there isn't any configuration for that. You can create your custom function like this:

```
function my_asset($path, $secure = null){
    return asset('/assets/' . trim($path, '/'), $secure);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I was also in a situation to use the S3 as a file provider. After searching the Laravel document, I found the following solution. You can configure the asset URL host by setting the ASSET_URL variable in your .env file.

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/helpers#method-asset

Answer (score 6):

Overriding default `asset()` is a bad idea but you can do it by [defining your own helper implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37339475/how-to-create-helper-methods-on-laravel-not-a-facade/37339565#37339565):

```
function asset($path, $secure = null)
{
    return app('url')->asset($path.'/asset', $secure);
}
```

But it's a better way to define your own helper like `customAsset()`.

Answer (score 4):

according to laravel 8.x documentation you can configure the asset URL host by setting the ASSET_URL variable in your .env file.

in your case in your .env file:

ASSET_URL=/public/assets

if changes do not take place, remember to run
php artisan config:clear