# Laravel 7 - not getting storage image path correctly

Tags: laravel, laravel-storage

I am unable to fetch the correct image URL to display in view using the asset. The generated URL required `storage` which is missing in it when I use the `asset` function and I have to manually add `storage` in the path like `asset('storage/' . $post->image)`

**I don't understand why the Laravel doesn't add `storage` automatically?**

### symlink storage

I have created a symlink of storage folder using the following command

```
php artisan storage:link
```

> **Question:**
> What I am looking for is the `storage` folder should be dynamically added to the path so I have to pass only `$post->image`.

### Controller

```
public function store(PostRequest $request)
{
    // upload the image to storage
    $image = $request->image->store('posts', 'public');

    // create the post
    Post::create([
        'title'       => $request->title,
        'description' => $request->description,
        'content'     => $request->content,
        'image'       => $image,
    ]);

    // redirect with flash message
    return redirect(route('posts.index'))->with('success', 'Post is created');

}
```

### DB `image` Column Stored Path

```
posts/ibexiCvUvbPKxzOLSMHQKPpDq7eZXrFA0stBoPfw.jpeg
```

### View

```
<tbody>
@foreach($posts as $post)
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="{{asset($post->image)}}"  width="60" height="60" alt="">
        </td>
        <td>{{ $post->title }}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
</tbody>
```

### Storage Path

[image]

### HTML Source

[image]

As you can see in the above references to get the correct URL I have to add `storage` into `asset('storage/'. $post->image)`

Comment: Hope this this works for you -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50185273/laravel-5-4-storage-link

Comment: try <HostName>/storage/posts/<image-name-from-database>, it should work

Comment: This link might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30191330/laravel-5-how-to-access-image-uploaded-in-storage-within-view

Comment: @mightyteja this I know and already have a symlinked storage folder. My question is how can I avoid adding `storage` folder in the path so I can get the image directly using the table column `$post->image`. Please read the last line in question.

Comment: You can create your custom helper to use instead `asset`. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43493148/change-the-asset-helper-url-in-laravel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `Storage::url()` function

```php
<tbody>
@foreach($posts as $post)
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="{{ Storage::url($post->image)}}"  width="60" height="60" alt="">
        </td>
        <td>{{ $post->title }}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
</tbody>
```

ref link https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/filesystem#file-urls

Answer (score 0):

another way that can be helpful is using ASSET_URL in your .env file such as:

```
APP_URL=http://localhost:8000
ASSET_URL = http://localhost:8000/storage
```

I appended 'storage' on my APP_URL to change default patch of asset helper function, then you can use asset function into your view such as this:

```
 <img src="{{asset($post->image)}}"  width="60" height="60" alt="">
```

I hope this way can help you.