# Check if Auth User role id matches array in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to evaluate an array of roles for an auth user. 100 and 102 are the role values I want to check. If the Auth user has one of these then return `true`. Is this possible? Here is my code so far:

```
if (Auth::user()->role_id == ([100, 102]) {
//process code here. A lot of code. 
}
```

I don't wish to repeat and check one at a time as the processing code is a lot and will make file lengthy.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers#method-array-has

Comment: go with [in_array](http://php.net/in_array) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) will definitely work for you:

```
if (in_array(auth()->user()->role_id, [100, 102]))
```

In this case, you could also define a [global helper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37339475/how-to-create-helper-methods-on-laravel-not-a-facade/37339565#37339565) to check if current user belongs to some role or role group:

```
if (! function_exists('isAdmin')) {
    function isAdmin()
    {
        return in_array(auth()->user()->role_id, [100, 102]);
    }
}
```

Then you'll be able to use this helper in controllers, models, custom classes etc:

```
if (isAdmin())
```

And even in Blade views:

```
@if (isAdmin())
```

Comment: @EdenWebStudio what exactly?

Comment: On you answer in the link, you ref adding the Helper file to composer autoload. Does it work to use public function register in service provider?

Comment: @EdenWebStudio yes, it will work if you'll include helpers file in service provider. But I think a better way is to use `composer.json` to autoload the file.

Answer (score 1):

```
As hassan said you can use in_array()

$a= Auth::user()->role_id;
$b= in_array(100, $your_array);
$c= in_array(102, $your_array);

if ( $a == $b && $a == $c ) {
  //process code here. A lot of code. 
}
```