# How to override Session::get?

Tags: laravel, session, laravel-5.3, laravel-session

We need to do custom logic at `Session::get` like for example, for some reason, if it gets a null value do something else before returning null to the caller..

We had a look at extending the session [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/session#adding-custom-session-drivers) but the handler that we need to override is at `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Store.php` with method `get`

So, what is the recommended way to achieve the overriding of method `get` at `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Store.php` ?

Comment: Could you explain why you need this behavior?

Answer (score 2):

You can create your own `SessionServiceProvider`, extending `Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider\SessionServiceProvider` and override `registerSessionDriver()` in order to return a custom instance of the store class.

Then comment the `Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider\SessionServiceProvider` in config/app.php and add your custom `SessionServiceProvider`.

A working example: https://gist.github.com/thiagorb/d4f4afaafa23a7a564b5675db952fbb2

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin, you don't need to reimplement them, you can just extend  them.

Comment: You can't just extend one method this way. You still need to override a lot of stuff (and then maintain the code). It's a huge overkill for a small extension. Also, I'm pretty sure that the most of the developers couldn't even do that because it's a complex task and not just some method overriding.

Comment: I don't agree with your opinion. These classes are supposed to be easy to extend. That's the whole purpose of having service providers. You should be able to replace the implementation easily.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin, I added a gist with an working implementation. Note that I implemented even the encrypted store, so this solution is very generic.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't test it, but I suppose you did. So you've created 4 classes and edited `config/app.php`. Now your team should worry about maintaining these 4 classes (thank god it's just 4 in this case). Would you really do this in a real project instead of creating or overriding a global helper or some method in `Helpers` class? Upvote for the effort anyway.

Comment: I can imagine situations where I would. Depending on how big the project already is. I don’t think these 4 classes add much complexity. Service providers are used often in the framework, so I would say they are like configuration. Besides that, depending on how the post author want the system to behave, it might be a good option. You need to take into account also that this solution is absolutely generic, without any other assumption about the rest of the system. It would work with existing modules and so on. So in the end it is just a matter of choosing between trade offs.

Answer (score 1):

You could [create](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37339475/how-to-create-helper-methods-on-laravel-not-a-facade/37339565#37339565) your own [`session()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers#method-session) like helper:

```
function sessionCheck($value)
{
    if (is_null(session($value))) {
        // Do something
    }

    return session($value);
}
```

Or override the existing one.