# Laravel domain group without having to pass domain parameter to controllers

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

I have all my routes in a domain group but I would like to avoid having the domain as a parameter in each controller method.

So I would like to avoid having this everywhere:

```
public function show($domain, $id) {}
```

and would like to just keep it as

```
public function show($id) {}
```

I was able to partially make it work with `$request->route()->forgetParameter('subdomain')` placed in a middleware but it doesn't work in the case of calling `redirect()->action('SomeController@show')` from a controller method.

---

### Here are some more details:

First, all routes are in a domain group.

```
Route::middleware(['some_middleware'])->domain('{subdomain}' .website.com)->group(function () {

    // .. All routes

}   );
```

Then, in **some_middleware** I have

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next) {

    // .. 

    $request->route()->forgetParameter('subdomain');

    return $next($request);
}
```

Then where it doesn't work:

```
class SomeController {

    public function process()
    {
        // ...

        redirect()->action('SimpleController@show', ['simple' => $id]);
    }
}
```

The error I'm getting is:

`Missing required parameters for [Route: ] [URI: simples/{simple}].`

This only works if I explicitly pass in the **subdomain** variable.

```
class SomeController {

    public function process()
    {
        // ...

        redirect()->action('SimpleController@show', ['subdomain'=>'some_subdomain', 'simple' => $id]);
    }
}
```

Can anyone suggest a "fix" for this? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2):

With Laravel 5.5+, you can use URL::defaults to set request-wide values for things like the route helper.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/urls#default-values

```php
public function handle($request, Closure $next) {

    // .. 
    $subdomain = $request->route('subdomain');

    URL::defaults(['subdomain' => $subdomain]);

    $request->route()->forgetParameter('subdomain');

    return $next($request);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a wrapper [helper](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37339565/1227923) for the `action()` helper:

```
if (! function_exists('actionSub')) {
    function actionSub($name, $parameters)
    {
        return action($name, $parameters + ['subdomain' => request()->route('subdomain')]);
    }
}
```

Then use it:

```
redirect(actionSub('SimpleController@show', ['simple' => $id]));
```

If someone has a more elegant solution for this, it will be great to see it.