# How to make global functions and class in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

I created `encrypt()` and `decrypt()` using `openssl_encrypt()`.
I want to use these methods from my server code globally. What is the best approach to implement this using Laravel?

Comment: If you're asking how to use your own global helpers https://stackoverflow.com/a/37339565/1227923. If you're asking about how to use these function from another server, it's a bad idea. It's better to implement the same functionality on the same server.

Comment: I recommend following the instructions here: https://laravel-news.com/creating-helpers

Answer (score 2):

**The basic steps are:**

Create a Helper file in `app/Helpers` dir. Put your function in that file and then add the file to `files` property of your `composer.json`

**ex:**

```
"autoload": {
        "classmap": [
             "database/seeds",
             "database/factories"
         ],
         "psr-4": {
              "App\\": "app/"
         },
         "files": [
               "app/Helpers/Indian_currency_format.php"
         ]
   },
```

**Then run:**

`composer dump-autoload` to load the file into composer autoload.

Then you can use the function in any of your controllers or views!

**More:**

I wrote a blog post about this a while ago which covers the process in detail. [See Here](https://www.kerneldev.com/2017/12/05/how-to-add-a-global-function-in-laravel-using-composer/)

Answer (score 1):

Used common function any file like controller,models and all blade file valid.

Please try your helpers.php file inner created.

file path like : laravel/app/helpers.php

Code

```
if (!function_exists('classActivePath')) {

   function classActivePath($path) {
       return Request::is($path) ? ' class="active"' : '';
   }

}
```