# Laravel 5.5 - Only Get Admin Users

Tags: php, laravel

I am getting a users details in a Laravel 5.5 controller like this...

```
$user = Auth::user();
```

But I want to do a check and see if the user has 'user_type' set to 'admin'

I know I can do a further check once I have the users info but is there a way to combine this into the one statement?

Comment: Like?: `$user = Auth::user()->user_type=='admin' ? 'Auth::user() : ''`

Comment: Are you using 2 different tables for user and it's roles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a method in User model:

```
public function isAdmin()
{
    return $this->user_type === 'admin';
}
```

Then use it anywhere in your code:

```
if (auth()->user()->isAdmin())
```

Or just do it manually each time:

```
if (auth()->check() && auth()->user()->user_type === 'admin')
```

You can even [create a global helper](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37339565/1227923) and do this:

```
@if (isAdmin())
```

Answer (score 1):

This way you can retrieve the `user_type` of the authenticated user:

```
$user = Auth::user()->user_type;
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see [here](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/database/migrations/2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table.php), the default migration for users does not have a user_type. Hence, if you want to give users certain privileges, you'll have to create it first.

I recommand using a out-of-the-box package. You can (for example) use the package [laravel permissions and roles (by Spatie)](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission) to do the work for you.